# Create an mssql server on Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, linux

Is there a way to create an mssql server on Linux? Maybe using the [ODBC drivers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2016/10/20/odbc-driver-13-0-for-linux-released/)?

Comment: Install MSSQL on Linux, or connect to an installed instance _from_ Linux? Which are you asking about?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: FYI ODBC is a protocol to interact with the database, when you install ODBC drivers, it's to connect to a database supporting ODBC connections. So it's for *Clients* not *Servers*

Comment: Run a vm, install windows and then mssql, can't you just connect to a windows ssql server ?

Comment: @JonStirling install mssql on Linux

Comment: @MinaMichael Then you had your answer ~24 hours ago.

Comment: @JonStirling yeah just checked now, however it doesn't specify any installation instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just about a week ago *(like one day after I asked this question)* a public preview of sql server on linux became available. Wow X'D

Installation instructions are described [Here](http://www.sqlserveronlinux.com/).

...so in my case for Ubuntu:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

then

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server
```

then run this to configure it

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr-setup
```

and this is an extra command to check that everything's working okay

```
systemctl status mssql-server
```

...also it's almost unavoidable to install `mssql-tools` to work on the server (described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools#ubuntu)):

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

then

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install mssql-tools
```

I wish I could work on a gui though. There's DbVis but [I can't get it to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605666/work-on-mssql-localy-on-linux-using-dbvis-as-gui).

Answer (score 0):

It was recently announced by Microsoft that there is now a version of SQL Server that can be installed on Linux. The announcement is below;

https://blogs.microsoft.com/blog/2016/03/07/announcing-sql-server-on-linux/